# Insert a line break before a numeric field or before an alphanumeric field that is just after a numeric field

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, regular-expression

I have this line

```
word1 word2 1234 4567 word3 8901 word4 word5 2541 5142 word5
```

I want to split this line in order to insert a line break before a numeric field or before an alphanumeric field that is just after a numeric field, so the output would be:

```
word1 word2
1234
4567
word3
8901
word4 word5
2541 
5142 
word5
```

All alphanumeric fields begin with letters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to preserve spaces between alphanumeric words and converts all other ones to newlines, so maybe:

```
perl -pe 's{([^\d\s]\S*\s+)(?=\S*[^\d\s])|\s+}{$1//"\n"}ge'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "word1 word2 1234 4567 word3 8901 word4 word5 2541 5142 word5" |perl -pe 's/(\s)([0-9]+)/$1\n$2/g; s/(\s)([0-9]+)(\s+)([a-zA-Z])/$1$2\n$4/g;'
```

Explanation:

- `perl -pe`:  run the following Perl script on each line of input and
  print results
- `s/(\s)([0-9]+)/$1\n$2/g`:  whitespace + numeric field
  -> whitespace + **newline** + numeric field
- `s/(\s)([0-9]+)(\s+)([a-zA-Z])/$1$2\n$4/g`:  whitespace + numeric
  field + whitespace + alphanumeric field -> whitespace + numeric field + **newline** + alphanumeric field
- the `g` at the end of each replacement means 'global'--do it for the entire line

Answer (score 1):

Put the following code in an awk script. Let's say the script is called  `do_magic.awk`

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

{
  str=$1
   for (i=2;i<=NF;++i) 
      if ($i ~ /^[0-9]+/) str = str "\n" $i "\n"
      else str = str " " $i
       gsub(/\n[[:space:]]*/,"\n",str)
       print str
}
```

Call the script using

`do_magic.awk yourfile`

Result is:

```
word1 word2
1234
4567
word3
8901
word4 word5
2541
5142
word5
```

PS: I had somehow a working solution I thought. On freenode #awk, `geirha`  provided the full answer. So credits go to him!